# Get ellipse element by id shadowroot open

Tags: javascript, web-component

I have a card web-component. In each card we have an ellipse element with unique id

All ids are numeric

```
<div class="card">
  <div class="timmer-mobile ">
    <div class="ellipse" id="timeForCount " data-time="73">
      <svg viewBox="-10 -10 250 120">
        <ellipse id="57" cx="100" cy="50" rx="100" ry="50" ></ellipse>
      </svg>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Im trying to get the ellipse element id with this code:

```
const ellipse = this.shadowRoot.getElementById="ellipse#"+id;
```

Result being `ellipse#50`

Now the problem is when I try to add to the ellipse a style with this code:

```
ellipse.style.strokeDasharray = `0, 1000`;
```

I get error:

```
'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'strokeDasharray')'
```

My guess is the selector is not working or the way I'm doing it .

Trying to add that style for each ellipse

```
ellipse.style.strokeDasharray = `0, 1000`;
```

Comment: `getElementById="ellipse#"+id;` you're overwriting the `getElementById` method. You want `this.shadowRoot.getElementById("ellipse#"+id);`

Comment: I get null if i use this.shadowRoot.getElementById("ellipse#"+id);

Comment: Get in the habit of reading documentation on methods you're using, don't guess at them. [getElementById](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) finds an element with the ID you passed in. If you're trying to get the ellipse element, either give it an ID, or look for elements with the `ellipse` tag name [getElementsByTagName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByTagName)

Comment: fixed, I called the function after some elements loaded on page.